# Tensorflow automatically deletes old model files

Tags: tensorflow

I use tf.train.Supervisor to start a session to train my model, and save model parameter every 1000 steps. But it seems that tensorflow would automatically delete old model files. Only 5 recent models were saved. Once model.ckpt-6000 is produced, the model.ckpt-1000 is deleted. But I can not find any documents on this operation.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the docs:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver

It has a variable called max_to_keep which defaults to 5.  So just call

```
tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=100000)
```

or some other large number that encompasses all that might be created.  No way to save all models as an option that I know of.

Update: as Ferran Parés points out in a comment just set max_to_keep=None to save all of the outputs.

```
tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=None)
```

Comment: It is possible to set `tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=None)` in order to save all models as pointed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38837404/5234494.