# Why I got less than the expected number of files when saving the results from TensorFlow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm working in Python 3.6 with TensorFlow but the problem that the `saver.save` is not working properly. 
I have to save nine different `sess` to nine files `model_path`but I got only five files and when I print the  `sess` and `model_path` I got nine results.

```
def save_models(sess, model_path):
    """ Save models to the current directory with the name filename """

    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    model_path = os.path.join(current_dir, "model/" + model_path)
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(model_path)):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(model_path))
    saver.save(sess, model_path, write_meta_graph=False)
```

I got these files which means that it only saves from `agent_3` and the `model_path` start from `agent_0`

[image: The files]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are [checkpoint files](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoints). 
By default, TF will save a checkpoint every 10 mins and **retain the 5 most recent checkpoints**. ([source](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoints#checkpointing_frequency)).

We can override this behaviour by passing the optional `max_to_keep` parameter. By default, it is set to 5 and cleans up the old checkpoints. If you set this to `0` it will not clean up any files:

```
saver.save(sess, model_path, write_meta_graph=False, max_to_keep=0)
```

It should be said in passing that, in general, one does not need to keep old checkpoints unless we want to restore the model to a state it was in early in training but that's (of course) your call.

Comment: The problem is that It only saves from `agent_3` and the `model_path` start from `agent_0`.

Comment: @your answer is totally right  but the problem is that `saver.save(sess, model_path, write_meta_graph=False, max_to_keep=0)` will not work but what is working is this `saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=9)`

Comment: I got the right answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38837309/tensorflow-saver-has-5-models-limit